# Is there a size limit in Videogular?

Tags: angularjs, videogular

I have a 86MB file that won't play but have other smaller mp4 that will. Is Videogular a streaming component or does it load the entire mp4 and then play it. I also do not get any errors, just the loading screen/circle goes forever.

thx
Ralph

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit but your file should be correctly encoded to play your file on-demand.

If you have problems with your MP4 just [try the file that we have at our website](http://www.videogular.com/assets/videos/videogular.mp4).

If you need help encoding your files you can use a transcoding software like [eRightSoft SUPER](http://www.erightsoft.com/SUPER.html) or an online service like [Zencoder](https://zencoder.com/en/) or [Encoding](http://www.encoding.com/).